# Form with simple-captcha not showing and no errors

Tags: django

Django form with simple-captcha is not showing on the productions server with nginx and uwsgi. No errors in logs. But when running development server the form is showing.

What could be the problem?

Python 2.7.3
uwsgi 2.0.14

Comment: Did you restart  the nginx server?

Comment: Yes, but no effects